# jQuery UI How to point broken image links to correct file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

First of all, I'm new to jquery and jQuery UI and how to use it. I downloaded everything I need and moved it to my project folder. However I keep getting the following error because it is looking for a folder in my Downloads folder that I moved to my project folder. I got this error multiple times for all of the images in the folder. How do I fix this?

```
GET http://localhost:#####/Downloads/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.11.1.js:6128
```

Comment: the downloaded jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom is missing one of its image, probapaly you forget to move into your project check the file name in downloaded folder

Comment: Change the reference of your CSS file in your HTML ... I presume.  However with such a minimal amount of information *anything* is possible!

Comment: make a text search on the css files for: ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png or create an image using this name this is the same as the other images but, it has a different color only.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your project folder is (for example): `C:\Projects\`

You needed to move jQuery & jQuery UI into it.  So your folder/file structure should have:

c:\Projects\

- js\

  - jquery-xxxx.js
  - jquery-ui-xxxxx.js
- css\

  - jquery-ui-xxxx.css
  - images\ ((all images for jQuery UI here))

Basically, your jquery UI css is going to have a heap of css lines like this:

```
    background: #a6a6a6 url(images/ui-bg_dots-small_65_a6a6a6_2x2.png) 50% 50% repeat;
```

This means that wherever you have saved your jqUI css file, should also have an "images" folder which contains the images for the JQUI css!

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI has a number of images that should have come with it, they come in a folder called 'images' and should be placed in the same folder that you keep your jquery-ui css file.  Right now, it looks as if you are keeping your css file inside your download directory, so you would need to copy your images folder (It should be part of the jquery-ui zip file) there.

I would also recommend that you don't work off your download folder, and instead move your jquery-ui files to the folder where your actual project is.  Also make sure that you update your html file to point your link and script tags to the new proper directory.